# Rearrange a sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a sorted array in ascending order. I have to build a new array in such a way that the last element of the sorted array will be the first element of the new array and the first element of the sorted array will be next element of the new array and so on.
For example-

```
//if a[] is the sorted array.
a[]={1,2,3,4,5}

//output-
//b[] is the new array.
b[]={5,1,4,2,3}
```

My approach is-
Using two index `i` and `j`.

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; j< count; i++, j++)
{
    b[j] = a[count - (i + 1)];
    b[++j] = a[i];
}
```

Now Question is how to do this using only a single index i.e using only index `i` from my example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is probably better suited for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Based on your description it seems `b` should hold `{5, 1, 2, 3, 4}`. If that is not correct, can you explain how the array is constructed?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: it's an ambiguous explanation (which I first interpreted as you have), but seems the idea is to take values from alternating ends of the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    b[i] = a[i % 2 ? i / 2 : count - i / 2 - 1];
```

Explanation: `i % 2` checks if the `b` index being set is at an odd 0-based position: if so it takes from `a[i/2]`, otherwise it comes back the same `i/2` amount from the end of `a`, which is `a[count - 1]`, so `a[count - i/2 - 1]`.

See it run [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48038141a9f3dcfe).

Comment: Perfect timing, was about to post the same answer :)

Comment: But the question states that b is supposed to be filled by taking elements from the sides of 'a' inward, not just move the last element to the first spot...

Comment: @TonyD now you go out of bounds right away when i=0.

Comment: @PiotrPytlik: true again - careless.  Have corrected and posted a link for an online compiler.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++)
{
    b[2*i] = a[count - (i + 1)];
    b[2 * i + 1] = a[i];
}
if (count % 2)
{
    b[count - 1] = a [count / 2];
}
```